# Google Play Billing : how to simulate 'Account Hold' status (in debug/sandbox mode)

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing, aidl

Before November 2020, an Android app on Google Play has to manage 'Account Hold' status.

https://developer.android.com/distribute/play-policies

Question is: how to simulate 'Account Hold' status so that I can check that my app manages properly this status ?

It is not mentioned in the doc as far as I can see: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/test

Thanks.

Comment: Indeed it is really not clear to me what is expected precisely. In particular, does the app need to change any UI/flow for the "hold" functionality?

Comment: Have you received any other answers to this question? The docs don't explain what an app should do to support 'Account Hold'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What we've found today:

1. Use *Test Card, Always Approves* to begin the subscription
2. Go to phone settings > Accounts > your name > your Google account > Payments > Manage Subscriptions (or Play Store > Subscriptions)
3. Update the Payment Method for that subscription to use *Test Card, Always Declines*
4. After the 30min renewal timer runs out, you'll get a "On Hold" push notification
5. Look at your app, see how it's doing

This On Hold state only lasts for about 5mins before reverting to Canceled. So if you want to test how your app reacts to users fixing their card problem, make sure you Update your payment method to *Test Card, Always Approves* within that time window or you'll need to start over.

Comment: Thanks! How should the app react? It is not clear in the guidelines. Is it enough if I display the usual paywall screen as for users who are not yet subscribed ? Thanks.

Comment: Other question: how to test Account Hold with a subscription that has a Grace Period ? Indeed, as you mention, the account hold has a duration of 5 minutes in test mode ; but I have a 30 days grace period that probably induces at least 5 minutes of Grace Period in test mode... So, I cannot test the behaviour of my app during the 5 minutes of Account Hold. Do you have any feedback about testing Account Hold for an app with Grace Period ? Thanks !

Comment: See my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64461824/google-play-subscriptions-interference-between-account-hold-and-grace-period

Comment: During the On Hold state, I don't think your app should paywall, as the sub is not yet canceled. The 5min Hold (or up to 30 days in real, non-sandbox time) is a built-in grace period for people to get a new card delivered, updated. In our case, we've chosen to do nothing, use Google as the gatekeeper of when our app accounts revert to non-paid state.


Yes, testing On Hold is a real hassle.

Comment: Detailed test timing : https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/01/faster-renewals-for-test-subscriptions.html

Answer (score 0):

> Go to the Account > Subscriptions section of the Google Play app, click your test subscription, and change payment method to "Test instrument, always declines"