# Google Play subscriptions: interference between 'Account Hold' and 'Grace Period'

Tags: java, android, google-play, in-app-billing, google-play-billing

All developers received emails from Google saying that apps using subscriptions should manage the 'Account Hold' status from November 1st, 2020. See for example [here](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/06/new-features-to-acquire-and-retain-subscribers.html).

So, I am trying to check that my apps with subscriptions manage this 'Account Hold' status properly.

I followed the Test Procedure mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63844352/google-play-billing-how-to-simulate-account-hold-status-in-debug-sandbox-mo).

The problem is that the 'Account Hold' status has a duration of only 5 minutes in Test Mode. But my subscriptions all have a Grace Period of 30 days in production ; what is the duration of this Grace Period in Test Mode ? Is it 5 minutes ? If yes, it means that I just can't see the 'Account Hold' in Test Mode because it is 'hidden' by the Test Grace Period.

Consequently, what I can see is that my app remains unlocked during the 5 minutes 'Account Hold' period and converts directly to a 'sub cancelled' status after that. So, my app is locked again and the Paywall displayed.

Question 1 : how to test the 'Account Hold' status for apps with Grace Period ?

More generally, I wonder if the management of the 'Account Hold' status is relevent for apps with Grace Period. Indeed, in my case, I have a Grace Period of 30 days in production. So, the user can use the app during 30 days even if the payment method didn't work. The user will directly loose access to the premium features after 30 days. I don't see where I have to manage the 'Account Hold' status.

So, Question 2: do apps with Grace Period have to manage 'Account Hold' status ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that during account hold,  you should block the access to your premium content. During grace period, you can allow the user to view it.
If your app has grace period of 30 days, then you're right, it makes it kind of unnecessary.
I have not yet seen grace period being testable in the test environment.

As for the 2nd question, yes. All apps need to have it enabled.

I think the point of having account hold is to keep a consistent purchase token. During the account hold when the user updates their payment, the purchase token will remain the same.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the two sentences "If your app has grace period of 30 days, then you're right, it makes it kind of unnecessary." and "2nd question, yes. All apps need to have it enabled" seem contradictory. Do I have have to take care of 'Account Hold' status if I have a 30 day Grace Period or not ? Thanks.

Comment: You do. All apps selling subscriptions need it.

Comment: I just said that if the grace period is 30 days, then yes it makes lesser sense to have account hold for 30 more days on top. But you do need it.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to enter "Account Hold" status once the 30 day Grace Period is finished ?

Answer (score 0):

Question 1: If you have both the account hold and grace period, the account hold applies after the grace period is over. If payment fails, block access to content and attempt to retry payment for 30 days. Applies after the grace period.

Question 2: yes, Account hold is required.